# How to display multiple select options in Sweetalert2 with VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2

I want to configure Sweetalert2 modal in such a way in which I am able to select different options from a list. This was easily achieved using the following code:

```
swal({
  title: 'Select Outage Tier',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    '1': 'Tier 1',
    '2': 'Tier 2',
    '3': 'Tier 3'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'required',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value !== '') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject('You need to select a Tier');
      }
    });
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result.value) {
    swal({
      type: 'success',
      html: 'You selected: ' + result.value
    });
  }
});
```

It was copied from a different question and it worked like a charm for the first part of my project. I can add new options in the `inputOptions: {}` tag. However, I want to display the options dynamically without having to change the code manually every time add/remove one.

I am retrieving the options from a database, by calling an API. This part was also done quickly and it works pretty well. I retrieve the data and store in a variable `options: ''`. The data is stored and ready to be used with the above code.

HERE COMES THE PROBLEM: I am still pretty new to VueJS and all I can do for now is basic coding. I tried to use a code snippet, from my own project, inside the `inputOptions: {}` tag, hoping it will work in the same way it works inside a method:

```
  inputOptions: {
   this.options.forEach((option) => {
      option.id : option:name
    });
  },
```

However, it doesn't work at all. I get an error Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` on the second line of the snippet code above.

All I want to do is to retrieve and display the options, from the database, inside the Sweetalert2 modal. Is there an easier, more efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `computed` property to prepare data for `inputOptions`

```
computed: {
  optionsDict() {
     if (!this.options) return {}
     return this.options.reduce((a, c) => {
      a[c.id] = c.name
      return a
     }, {})
  }
}
```

and then

```
swal({
  ...
  inputOptions: this.optionsDict
  ...
})
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I am really impressed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, could you explain the code a little? I want to understand the process and not only copy paste it.

Comment: `inputOptions` is an object, you need to prepare properly formatted data for it. And the most convenient way is using `computed` property. You can check the official document at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html